# Changine iPhone's wallpaper while playing music

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I wonder if it's possible to change the wallpaper on the iPhone's lock screen while music is playing. I want to do exactly what the Music app does. I thought that is a closed API, but I discovered that the Spotify app does it too!

I'm looking in .plist for this but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).